# set Datagridviewcombocell value to any string or textbox.text

Tags: visual-studio-2010

i am stuck with a problem i hope the solution may be quit an easy one but could not get it. After searching though varios forums and applying my head to the exhuation i seek my answer here.

Ok now, my problem is that I have a textbox as tb116 ,

a datagridview as tv1 has 5 columns (with  column(1)) as datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

bound to datatable as dt  ,having valuemember and displaymember defined

and a list as t1

on my form. Now when tb116 gets focus t1 is shown , when t1 is selected or clicked i get text for tb116 and same needs to be shown in  column(1) ..further i also want to set text in  column(1)  from a string or another textbox.....

Pls help it very urgent

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs help on this topic

refer to my other thread

"set Datagridviewcombocell value to any string or textbox.text"

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/visualstudiogeneral/thread/477caf5f-09c3-4590-a06e-b3d91f58a87d

or You can reply with ur email on this thread.